# Django tries localhost on Mysql but I say otherwise

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to make Django work under Windows 10 but connecting with my (often used) off-site Mysql server I get

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

While (like I used to do) state in my config file (mysql.conf) to which is pointed to by my settings.py like I used a thousand times before:

```
[client]
host = 10.8.0.1
database = sitesv
user = niels
password = xxx
port = 3306
default-character-set = utf8
```

Whether I use the ip within '' or I use a name which is known in my hosts file I still get the same stupid error.... I'm not trying localhost!

In site/settings.py I (still) have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': BASE_DIR+'\sv\mysql.conf',
        },
    }
}
```

With 'still' I mean that I am not frustrated but just halted by some minor mistake which I don't see. ;)

Comment: Shouldn't you use `bind-address = 10.8.0.1`?

Comment: In de mysql.conf file?

Comment: Then I get django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (0)")

Comment: So django can't do this under windows 10 but it can under linux :D

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing here. What db host do you have in your settings.py?

Comment: None, i only refer to the mysql.conf, which is stated above, I will add my site/settings.py shortly... bear with me :)

Comment: By the way the back-slashes did not make any difference :) and bind-address (@WillemVanOnsem) did made the difference to which I apparently can login but not properly communicate. I also switched off TLS on the MySQL connection (server side) but that did not help... I'm in the dark and need this :):)

Comment: The connection has been checked from the same VPN I should be in and works fine with Ubuntu Mysql client d.d. 2019-08-11 being up to date.